# Is it planned to incorporate the Olson database for TZ in POSIX for `date`?

Tags: date, timezone

There is a simpler way to define the value of the timezone, [the Olson database](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/au-aix-posix/).
It has been [supported for 19 years (Paul Eggert)](https://tz.iana.narkive.com/vLVA4n74/list-of-time-zones-compliant-both-for-linux-solaris-5-8-osf1-tru64-hp-ux#post2) by Solaris, HP-UX and Tru64.
It is certainly supported by AIX as the first link demonstrates.
And [by all BSD's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

But there is no mention of it in POSIX.

It is simple:

```
TZ=America/New_York
```

And it is better as it is immune to changes in DST. And takes into account DST changes for different years.

```
$ TZ="America/New_York" faketime "Sun Mar 10 03:00:00 2012" date &&
> TZ="America/New_York" faketime "Sun Mar 10 03:00:00 2013" date

Sat 10 Mar 2012 03:00:00 AM EST
Sun 10 Mar 2013 03:00:00 AM EDT
```

Related:

- [Supported by Solaris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211425/changing-timezone-in-oracle-solaris-11-2)
- [There are 561 time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, there’s no such plan; no open bug in [the Austin Group bug tracker](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/) references [the time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), it hasn’t been discussed on the mailing list, and it doesn’t appear in the meeting minutes.

POSIX was improved in 2019 to incorporate one feature from the Olson database, times outside the 0-24 range; see [bug 1252](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1252) for details.

Strictly speaking, as I understand it, Olson entries should be requested using `TZ=:...`; `TZ` values starting with a colon [are specified as implementation-defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).

Comment: [Solaris](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-set-the-timezone-in-solaris-1011/), [AIX](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/systems/articles/au-aix-posix/) both use TZ without a `:`, both are POSIX certified, so, there should be a misunderstanding or there is some other way to do that.

Comment: In many implementations, if you use `:`, the timezone code will look directly for the corresponding Olson entry; if you don’t, it will try to parse the timezone specification, and if that fails, look for a corresponding Olson entry. My point is that as I understand it, an implementation is *allowed* to fail (whatever that ends up meaning) if `TZ` isn’t either a valid timezone description (in POSIX format) or a value starting with `:` (and valid then according to the implementation-defined rules).

Answer (score 1):

I remember there was a related longer discussion in the telephone conference.

It has been discussed whether the olson database should be included. As a result of the complexity of the database, no agreement could be found to include a copy of the spec, nor to make a reference to that spec.

As a result, the olson based method stays a permitted extension that is bejond the scope.